# Omit validation for p:selectOneMenu, for Ajax requests

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a Jsf page with a fragment with `<p:selectOneMenu/>` (Prime faces) and an Ajax associated with it. It have the default select item "--- Select One ---" and others items that were created dynamically.

This field is required, so if users submit the form without select, the page show a error message.

The problem occurs when I select one of this others options and go back selecting "--- Select One ---"  again. Then the page shows the required field message, even before I submit the form. I try different ways of `immediate` in `<p:ajax>` and `<p:selectOneMenu>` tags but none of them has the expected behavior.

The `<p:messages>` is declared as below:

-- list.xhtml

```
<p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"  escape="false" />
<.... include fragment.xhtml ....>
```

And the fragment:

-- fragment.xhtml

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectTipoCarro"
                 value="#{carroBean.carro.tipoCarroEnum}"
                 required="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{carroBean.listaSelectItemTipoCarroInclusao}" />
    <p:ajax update="outputInicioVigenciaWrapper outputLabelCalendarInicioVigenciaWrapper"
            listener="#{carroBean.aoMudarTipoCarro}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="outputLabelCalendarInicioVigenciaWrapper">
    <h:outputLabel id="outputLabelCalendarInicioVigencia"
                   rendered="#{carroBean.edicaoDataInicioVigenciaDisponivel}"
                   for="calendarInicioVigencia">
        <span>*
            #{labels['carro.inicio.vigencia']}: </span>
        <p:calendar id="calendarInicioVigencia"
                    value="#{carroBean.carro.dataInicioVigencia}"
                    showOn="button"
                    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true"
                    required="true"/>
    </h:outputLabel>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="outputInicioVigenciaWrapper">
    <h:outputLabel for="outputInicioVigencia"
                   rendered="#{not carroBean.edicaoDataInicioVigenciaDisponivel}">
        <span aria-live="polite">
            <h:outputText id="outputInicioVigencia"
                          value="#{carroBean.carro.dataInicioVigencia}"
                          styleClass="dataFormat"
        </h:outputText>
    </span>
</h:outputLabel>
</h:panelGroup>
```

```
private SelectItem obterSelectItemSelecione() {
    SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem("", "-- Select One --");
    return selectItem;
}

private void preencherListaSelectItemTipoCarro(List<SelectItem> select, TipoCarroEnum[] tiposCarrosConsiderados) {
    select.clear();
    select.add(obterSelectItemSelecione());
    for (TipoCarroEnum tipoCarro : tiposCarrosConsiderados) {
        select.add(new SelectItem(tipoCarro, tipoCarro.getNome()));
    }
}

public void aoMudarTipoCarro() {
    getCarro().setDataInicioVigencia(carroService.obterProximaDataInicioVigenciaDisponivel(getCarro().getTipoCarroEnum()));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation**

This happens because you have a `p:messages` component with `autoUpdate` set to true and you have attached `p:ajax` to your selectOneMenu so anytime your value changes, `p:messages` is updated. Therefore, due to the use of `required="true"` an error messages is shown as soon as you have selected "--- Select One ---".

**Solution**

- Add `ignoreAutoUpdate="true"` to your `p:ajax` or
- Remove `autoUpdate="true"` if not necessary

Comment: This will only avoid the message being displayed, but won't set the selected value in the bean in case of no selection. Validation phase is not skipped, indeed.

Comment: In that case It's ok since I just need the value after submitting the form. The listener is only for update components inside both panel groups.

Comment: @alexpfx aren't you updating them based in your selection value? Then why call a listener method in your bean?

Comment: @XtremeBiker Sorry, you are right. I use the select value in method "aoMudarTipoCarro".

Comment: @XtremeBiker But, testing it, I can't see wrong behavior. I put a breakpoint in the method 'aoMudarTipoCarro' and the value of getCarro().getTipoCarroEnum() is consistent with what I've selected...

Answer (score 4):

That's **the expected behaviour**. When adding a `p:ajax` tag to your `p:selectOneMenu` you make the value be processed everytime the user changes the input, so it will be validated and rejected if you mark it as `required`. My favourite workaround for this cases is to include a request param in the button to submit the whole form and check for it in the `required` attribute. That's it:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:comp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/comp"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{val}"
            required="#{param['validate']}">
            <p:ajax event="change" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="None" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="val1" itemValue="val1" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false">
            <f:param name="validate" value="true" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**See also:**

- [Conditionally skip JSF validation but perform model updates](http://szimano.org/conditionally-skip-jsf-validation-but-perform-model-updates/)