# Submit form but ignore required="true" with f:ajax

Tags: jsf

I have a simple form like the one below with two buttons.

```
<h:form>

    <h:inputText required="#{empty param[save.clientId]}"
        value="#{bean.a}" id="a" />

    <h:inputText required="#{empty param[save.clientId]}"
        value="#{bean.b}" id="b" />

    <h:commandButton binding="#{save}" value="WORKING SAVE JSF"
        action="#{bean.submit}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />
    </h:commandButton>

    <h:commandButton value="WORKING SUBMIT JSF" action="#{bean.submit}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />
    </h:commandButton>
```

One button (save) should only pass the values (and exactly the values) to the model *without* validation.
The second one (submit) should validate the input fields and if there is no error, pass to the model.

It does work without `<f:ajax`> or with `<p:commandButton>`. But simply not with `<f:ajax>`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There are several related (almost) identical questions on stackoverflow. Try what is in them first

Comment: So similar to this question I answered last week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848032/omit-validation-for-pselectonemenu-for-ajax-requests/29848568#29848568

Comment: none of them seem to work for `f:ajax`.

Comment: I agree with tt_dev. It's all about `<f:ajax>`. It is also working without `<f:ajax`> fine. See updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working example.

on xhtml level, you should set a custom validator to your input fields:

```
    <h:form id="form">      
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.a}" >
            <f:validator validatorId="myCustomValidator"/>
        </h:inputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.b}" >
            <f:validator validatorId="myCustomValidator"/>
        </h:inputText>

        <h:commandButton id="noValidationButton" action="#{bean.submit}" value="Submit only">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:commandButton action="#{bean.submit}" value="Submit and validate">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:messages/>
    </h:form>
```

this custom validator class should check the event source by its exact id on rendered html (`form:noValidationButton` in this case), and just return if the button for "no validation" is clicked. it will look like this:

```
@FacesValidator("myCustomValidator")
public class MyCustomValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        String[] eventSource = ((HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getRequest()).getParameterMap().get("javax.faces.source");
        if (eventSource != null && 
            eventSource.length > 0 &&
            eventSource[0].equals("form:noValidationButton"))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // do regular validation here
            if (value == null || value.equals(""))
            {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("failed."));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the `web.xml` configuration below makes sure that jsf validates all submitted input values, even if they are left empty.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: That is looking nice. I have no time to test it now (You know why). I will comment it in a couple days. Can you please add some explanation?

Comment: sure, i had limited time when i first submitted the answer. i provided some explanation now.

Comment: On my testpage it is working like a charm! I will implement this to my current app. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know, how I can add a buttons which are present in a `<h:dataTable`> to the if-condition? I am struggeling with this. Those have all `IDs` like `:form:datatableID:index:buttonID`

Comment: @Alexander just check `eventSource[0].endsWith("noValidationButton")`, don't bother with the prior part of the id. but make sure you `execute` only the current (clicked) row with the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

To skip validation you can do like this-

```
<h:inputText required="#{param['req']=='1'}"
    value="#{bean.a}" id="a" />

<h:commandButton binding="#{save}" value="WORKING SAVE JSF"
    action="#{bean.submit}">
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />
<f:param id="req" value="1"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: How can I add a second button, where the validation is triggered correctly? The 'do not validate-thing' does indeed work.

Comment: Sorry i am not able to understand your question properly,  would you elaborate?

Comment: Basically: Two buttons. One should pass values without validation (ignore requried = true) and the other one should validate and pass values.

Comment: So according to thia the button in which you pass the parameter will check validation and one in which you won't pass parameter will skip validation.

Comment: Yes exactly. But how does the second button looks like? I tried some cases, but they dosnt work correctly. You may have a hint for me?